# Unsure how to use ' in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to remotely SSH into a server and remove x amount of backups depending how many we set to keep in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

BKUSER=4582
BKSERVER=int-backup2.domain.com


DELETEMORETHAN=$(ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" 'find ~/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l')
if [ "$DELETEMORETHAN" -gt 4 ] ; then
   COUNT=$(echo "$DELETEMORETHAN - 4" | bc -l)
   ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" 'echo rm -rvf "$(ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" 'find ~/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -"${COUNT}"')'
fi
```

In this example, I am trying to keep 4 of the latest backups.  I am failing at

```
ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" 'echo rm -rvf "$(ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" 'find ~/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -"${COUNT}"')'
```

I was trying to use: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2026 but it doesn't help since the ' are not being grouped properly, I am stuck!

---

dennis-b:

```
[root@ngx /]# ./test
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Escape it with `\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no point repeatedly ssh'ing into your server in order to construct a command line which will be executed that server. Just ssh once, and give it the script that should be run.

To simplify a bit, there is no real need to use `find`. `find ~/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type d` doesn't even produce the listing in order, so a simple glob `~/backup/*/` is probably better.

Assuming you have bash on the server,

```
ssh "$bkuser@$bkserver" \
    'dirs=(~/backup/*/);
     if ((${#dirs[@]} > 4)); then
       echo rm -rvf "${dirs[@]:4}";
     fi'
```

will probably do what you want. (Split into lines for readability; it can be typed all on one line, leaving out the line continuation character.)

Comment: Would there be anyway to ensure it keeps the 4 most recent backups

Comment: @jcats: if you name your backup directories properly, then an alphabetic sort of the names will give you the correct order. With the glob solution above, you'll need to change the slice to drop all but the last four elements, eg. `"${dirs[@]:0:${#dirs[@]}}"`. But the key is correct naming, because numeric and date sorts are a lot more work. I use `yyyymmddhhmmss`.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `'` and `"` is that variables in double quotes are replaced but in single quotes no variables are replaced and `$()` is not executed.

So to build the command that is to be executed on the server, you need to put it into double quotes as you need the `$()` to work:

```
ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" "echo rm -rvf '$(ssh "$BKUSER"@"$BKSERVER" "find ~/backup/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | head -'${COUNT}'")"
```

You basically have to switch your single and double quotes: the outermost quotes must be double quotes so `$()` works and variables are replaced. The quotes that are required for the command to work on the server can be single quotes, as no variable replacement happens on the server, everything is done before the command is send.

You may wonder why `'$(ssh ...)'` works in spite of being in single quotes. Actually, it is in double quotes! The single quotes are not quotes here, they are just plain text inside of double quotes. They only get interpreted as single quotes on the server.

Comment: Really appreciate the reply, super helpful! I am still encountering the same error though, just updated the question